# How to join a pandas data frame with a PeriodIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
df.index = df.index.to_period('Q')

if comb.empty:
    comp = df
else:
    comp = comp.join(df,how = 'outer')
```

When I do this I get: join() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'

This is what my original dataframe looks like. I am attempting to >change it to a quarter based PeriodIndex and then join it with another dataframe with the same type of PeriodIndex. Can anyone tell my why I keep getting this error?

[df dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Gev.png)

Comment: show your data to us ...

Comment: I wasn't exactly sure how to post the actual dataframes. If you can tell me how I can post them?

Comment: You can edit your question :-)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.